# Does the CVSS impact score correspond to probability?

Tags: attacks, known-vulnerabilities, cvss

From  http://nvd.nist.gov/cvsseq2.htm, I noticed that the CVSS standard attributes the following impact values ​​for confidentiality, integrity and availability:

> `0` for `none` impact,
>   `0.275` for `partial` impact and
>   `0.66` for `complete` impact.

My question is the following:
what theses scores really represent? Is these values correspond to probability ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they do not. They are impact scores.

The page you linked to in your previous question on this details it: http://nvd.nist.gov/cvsseq2.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can find a very thorough guide to CVSSv2 here http://www.first.org/cvss/cvss-guide.html. There is also the [CVSSv2 calculator](http://nvd.nist.gov/cvss.cfm?calculator&adv&version=2) which links to [the equations](http://nvd.nist.gov/cvsseq2.htm) it uses.